# Need to use an inner data Template that is the same as outer template

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have the following XML structure(simplified for example's sake) where you can have questions within questions. There are other types of questions so I have decided to make a template to display them, I can create the top level of questions show, but when i get to the inner levels I can't get my template to show. I do have other question types other than "string", but I removed them to try to focus on the issue at hand.

The XML structure

```
<QUESTIONS>
    <QUESTION id="3" text="What is this?" type="string">
        <QUESTIONS>
            <QUESTION id="7" text="What is the First Inner Question?" type="string">
                <QUESTIONS>
                    <QUESTION id="8" text="What is another inner Question?" type="string">
                    </QUESTION>
                </QUESTIONS>
            </QUESTION>
        </QUESTIONS>
    </QUESTION>
    <QUESTION id="4" text="Where another question?" type="string">
        <QUESTIONS>
            <QUESTION id="5" text="What is another inner question?" type="string">
                <QUESTIONS>
                    <QUESTION id="6" text="What is another inner question?" type="string">
                    </QUESTION>
                </QUESTIONS>
            </QUESTION>
        </QUESTIONS>
    </QUESTION>
  </QUESTIONS>
```

My XAML

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StringQuestionTemplate" DataType="models:FormQuestion" >

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=QuestionText}" />
            <TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=Answer, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <StackPanel>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InnerQuestions}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" />
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <templateIssue:QuestionTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector" 
                                    StringTemplate="{ StaticResource StringQuestionTemplate }" />

</Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Questions}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" >
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Here is the QuestionTemplateSelector

```
public class QuestionTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate StringTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        switch (((FormQuestion)item).Type)
        {
            case QuestionType.StringQuestion:
                return StringTemplate;
            default:
                return StringTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use the same template selector for the "InnerQuestions" as i do for the original templates, but since it is referenced after the  section I am not able to(an error is thrown). So I would like to use the same DataTemplate In the "InnerQuestions" as i do for the top level questions. Is there a way to accomplish this, either templating it using a different structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use the [`HierarchicalDataTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Something like this perhaps (assuming your `Binding`s are correct):

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="models:FormQuestion"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InnerQuestions}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=QuestionText}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Answer, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You also need to use a control that can display hierarchical data, like a `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TopLevelQuestions}" />
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it's still not recognizing {StaticResource TemplateSelector} because it comes after the section for HierarchicalDataTemplate. If i switch the two around, Then my questionTemplateSelector can't recognize my StringTemplate